# Jinja2 render template - ignore fields for which there is no value

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a default.yaml which has some properties like:

```
app_conf:
   port: 443
   ping_port: 444
```

I have a application.conf which looks like:

```
...
master_port "{{ app_conf.port }}";
pingcheck_port "{{ app_conf.ping_port }}";
...
```

I use the below python code to substitute the fields in the application.conf with the ones in default.yaml

```
configuration = yaml.load(open('conf/default.yaml'))['app_conf']
template = env.get_template("application.conf")
confReplaceOutput = template.render(app_conf=configuration)
```

Now, If the value for {{app_conf.ping_port}} is not available in the default.yaml file, then the rendered output is:

```
    pingcheck_port:;
```

I want the output to be

```
pingcheck_port "{{ app_conf.ping_port }}";
```

So How do i configure jinja2 to ignore the substitution for a field for which there is no definition in the yaml file??

Answer (score 0):

I would use if, else and raw blocks

```
{% if app_conf is defined and app_conf.ping_port is defined -%}
    pingcheck_port "{{ app_conf.ping_port }}";
{% else %}
    {%raw-%}
        pingcheck_port "{{ app_conf.ping_port }}";
    {%endraw%}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry, but where do i put this code? in the application.conf file?